# Uncaught Action failed: event.getSource is not a function not working for Lightning button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have an `aura:Iterate` in iterate i have a close icon onclick of that i will get an modal popup and i will give values and click on **submit** then modal will close and i want to make that button disable. below i am posting my code.

**Controller:**

```
rejcomment : function(component, event, helper) 
{ 
    component.set("v.isRejectOpen", false);
    component.find("v.IDFReject", "icn");
    var mydid = component.get("v.forselectedidf");
    alert('Before assigned');
    var btn = event.getSource();
    btn.set("v.disabled",true);
    alert('Assigned');
},
```

**Component:**

```
<lightning:button iconName="utility:close" aura:id="{!idf.Base_Invention_Disclosure__c}" variant="bare" disabled="false" class="{!v.IDFReject}" onclick="{!c.openrejModel}" value="{!idf.Base_Invention_Disclosure__c}" />
```

i have tried like this and i am getting following Error.[image]

Correct me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You can’t assign aura:id s in aura iterations dynamically

Comment: then is they any workaround for this ??

Comment: If you need uniqueness in an iteration, you can nest it under something like the `name` attribute. That said, your button click controller function is the one that needs to listen to `event.getSource()`. You can do `event.getSource().set("v.disabled", true)` directly from `c.openrejModel`